# What does this code from DuckTales mean?

Tags: disney, ducktales

In episode 17 of the new DuckTales, a sequence of binary numbers appears as follows:

010010101
0110101101
01101001

These translate in decimal to:

149
429
105

I may have mistranscribed the numbers (autocorrect...) but what do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It was intended to be a message, but the art department didn't do it according to [the Director's tweet](https://twitter.com/TannerTrue/status/1015641683625562112):

> In the Storyboard, Artist Ben Holm made the binary to read “Remember Number 4” implying that robo-goon Number 3 had been living in that cave mourning his fallen comrade for 40+ years. But, I imagine it was a bit too much detail for the BG design. Maybe the designer intended JKI?

Comment: Well done, that answers things very neatly, although I am a little sad that it ended up being nonsense.

Comment: If the designer intended JKI then what does JKI even mean?

Comment: @dannymcg No idea, but that's what that binary is in ASCII.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: But only if you choose to ignore the additional bits that make the first two groups longer than 8 bits.

Comment: Huh. I could have sworn I looked it up at the time and the ASCII seemed accurate, but you're right. The tweet has vanished as well, which makes me very glad I quoted it.